# How to fix the text absolutely in HTML/CSS even I minimize the screen

Tags: html, css

So right now I am trying to apply what I have learned in Front Web Development, and I have this problem where the text doesn't stay the way it should be in smaller viewports.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f2f2fc;
  color: #302e4d;
}

.about-section {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -60%);
}

.about-me div {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.intro {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.intro-stud {
  color: #E00;
}

.description {
  color: #504e70;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <section class="about-section">
    <div class="about-me">
      <div>About Me</div>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <span class="intro-name">I'm Christian Wells Martin and</span>
      <span class="intro-stud">a Student</span>
      <p class="description">Hi! My name is Christian Wells Martin, a BSIT/BSCS student in _____ College/University, and currently studying web development, and this website is my first mini-project, and I hope you guys will like it!.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Recommendations are welcome, specially if I am doing some wrong practices.

Comment: Your text probably needs a `margin-left` the size of the side menu. The true issue however would be that side nav would not be good practice in terms smaller viewports. I would recommend switching it to a top-nav in smaller viewports. Where you can use `@media` in CSS queries to achieve this. If you check the snippet I edited into your question, you will see it looks fine in a small viewport.

Comment: What’s your desired outcome? Perhaps you can ditch the absolute position and try to put the about-section and the sidebar under one div with `display:flex`. Set the sidebar width, and set the about-section to `flex-grow:1`, so the browser will distribute the unused space to your about-section.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to solve this.

One, you're using percentages in your absolute positioning. Percentages will change as the size of the window changes. This can make for a nice effect, but it doesn't seem to be what you're going for. Try using exact pixel values if you don't want your text to react responsively. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Another, more advanced way to solve this would be to use media queries. These allow you to define different css styles based on the current size of the screen. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
.about-section{
display:grid;
grid-template-rows:auto, 1fr;
}
```

That should solve your problem. If it is not try this one:

```
.about-section{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}
```